# Use regular expression to match ANY Chinese character in utf-8 encoding

Tags: regex, unicode, flex-lexer, non-english

For example, I want to match a string consisting of `m` to `n` Chinese characters, then I can use:

```
[single Chinese character regular expression]{m,n}
```

Is there some regular expression of a single Chinese character, which could be any Chinese characters that exists?

Comment: At the very least, please provide information on the regex engine you're using.

Comment: @KevinBallard I am not quite sure which engine I am using. What I know is I use the regular expression functionality in `flex`(the lexer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flex (lexical scanner) to read UTF-8 characters input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921648/how-to-make-a-flex-lexical-scanner-to-read-utf-8-characters-input)

Comment: flex won't do this; answers which assume it does do not address the question.

Answer (score 52):

The regex to match a Chinese (well, CJK) character is

```
\p{script=Han}
```

which can be appreviated to simply

```
\p{Han}
```

This assumes that your regex compiler meets [requirement **RL1.2** Properties from UTS#18 *Unicode Regular Expressions*](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories). Perl and Java 7 both meet that spec, but many others do not.

Comment: It is a pity that flex does not seem to support it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @xiaohan2012: I don't think flex really supports unicode at all

Comment: @xiaohan2012 If I were you, I would look into using using some of the lexing and parsing tools available under Perl or Java, which do support Unicode.

Comment: Is there a variant of this for C#

Comment: This worked perfect in Coda 2 find and replace. Thanks!

Comment: It gives `Unknown character property name {Han}` for Java-8. What's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps use [RE/flex](https://github.com/Genivia/RE-flex) as an alternative to Flex? It handles Unicode quite well and uses the same Flex syntax. I've also been unhappy with the lack of progress with Flex, so I created a new version (RE/flex) that understands modern Unicode and character encodings.

Comment: I find this rule is not supported by Impala.

Comment: @Andremoniy I believe you can use: `\p{IsHan}` in Java: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html

Answer (score 7):

In Java,

```
\p{InCJK_UNIFIED_IDEOGRAPHS}{1,3}
```

Comment: Note that this only finds characters in the block from U+4E00–U+9FFF. It does not find all Chinese characters that exist.

Comment: The question is tagged with the Flex lexer for C and C++ that does not support the `\p{C}` character block.

Answer (score 6):

In C#

```
new Regex(@"\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}")
```

Here it is in [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-named-blocks)

And here's more info from Wikipedia: [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs)

The basic block named CJK Unified Ideographs (4E00–9FFF) contains 20,976 basic Chinese characters in the range U+4E00 through U+9FEF. The block not only includes characters used in the Chinese writing system but also kanji used in the Japanese writing system and hanja, whose use is diminishing in Korea. Many characters in this block are used in all three writing systems, while others are in only one or two of the three. Chinese characters are also used in Vietnam's Nôm script (now obsolete).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To help improve your post, please consider adding a link to documentation, or add an explanation to help explain what this does.

Answer (score 3):

###### For most programming languages, the  regular expression to match 99.9%+ Chinese characters will be:

#### `\u4E00-\u9FFF`

*Works with: Python, modern Javascript, Golang, Rust **but not PHP**.*

Useful if your language don't support notations like `{Han}`/`{script=Han}`/`{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}` in other answers.

NB: This corresponds to the [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs), and includes other languages like Korean, Japanese and Vietnamese.

Comment: For input that accepts (or requires) Unicode encoded text, `[\u4E00-\u9FFF]` is equivalent to `[一-鿿]`

Comment: this matches roman characters as well

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some regular expression of a single Chinese character, which could be any Chinese characters that exists?

**Recommendation**

To match patterns with Chinese characters and other Unicode code points with a Flex-compatible lexical analyzer, try the RE/flex<sup>[1]</sup> lexical analyzer generator, that I developed and others have contributed to, to extend Flex++ with Unicode and other useful features.

For example, you can write Unicode patterns (UTF-8 regular expressions) in lexer specifications:

```
%option flex unicode
%%
[肖晗]   { printf ("xiaohan/2\n"); }
%%
```

`%option unicode` enables Unicode. You can also use a local modifier `(?u:)` to restrict Unicode to a single pattern (so everything else is still ASCII/8-bit as in Flex):

```
%option flex
%%
(?u:[肖晗])   { printf ("xiaohan/2\n"); }
(?u:\p{Han})  { printf ("Han character %s\n", yytext); }
.             { printf ("8-bit character %d\n", yytext[0]); }
%%
```

`%option flex` enables Flex compatibility, so you can use `yytext`, `yyleng`, `ECHO`, and so on.  Without the `flex` option RE/flex expects Lexer method calls: `text()` (or `str()` and `wstr()` for `std::string` and `std::wstring`), `size()` (or `wsize()` for wide char length), and `echo()`. RE/flex method calls include wide char operations.

**Background**

In plain old Flex I ended up defining UTF-8 patterns to capture ASCII letters and UTF-8 encoded letters for a compiler project that required support for Unicode identifiers `id`:

```
digit           [0-9]
alpha           ([a-zA-Z_\xA8\xAA\xAD\xAF\xB2\xB5\xB7\xB8\xB9\xBA\xBC\xBD\xBE]|[\xC0-\xFF][\x80-\xBF]*|\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4}))
id              ({alpha})({alpha}|{digit})*
```

The `alpha` pattern supports ASCII letters, underscore, and Unicode code points that are used in identifiers (`\p{L}` etc). The pattern permits more Unicode code points than absolutely necessary to keep the size of this pattern manageable, so it trades compactness for some lack of accuracy and to permit UTF-8 [overlong characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings) in some cases that are not valid UTF-8. If you are thinking about this approach than be wary about the problems and safety concerns.

**Safety**

When using UTF-8 directly in Flex patterns, there are several concerns:

1. Encoding your own UTF-8 patterns in Flex for matching any Unicode character may be prone to errors. Patterns should be restricted to characters in the valid Unicode range only.  Unicode code points cover the range U+0000 to U+D7FF and U+E000 to U+10FFFF. The range U+D800 to U+DFFF is reserved for UTF-16 surrogate pairs and are [invalid code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_code_points). When using a tool to convert a Unicode range to UTF-8, make sure to exclude invalid code points.
2. Patterns should reject [overlong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings) and other [invalid byte sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences). Invalid UTF-8 should not be silently accepted.
3. To catch lexical input errors in your lexer will require a special `.` (dot) that matches valid and invalid Unicode, including UTF-8 overruns and invalid byte sequences, in order to produce an error message that the input is rejected.  If you use dot as a "catch-all-else" to produce an error message, but your dot does not match invalid Unicode, then you lexer will hang ("scanner is jammed") or your lexer will ECHO rubbish characters on the output by the Flex "default rule".
4. Your scanner should recognize a [UTF BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark) (Unicode Byte Order Mark) in the input to switch to UTF-8, UTF-16 (LE or BE), or UTF-32 (LE or BE).
5. As you point out, patterns such as `[unicode characters]` do not work at all with Flex because UTF-8 characters in a bracket list are multibyte characters and each single byte character can be matched but not the UTF-8 character.

<sup>[1]</sup> https://github.com/Genivia/RE-flex

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 and up, the format should be: "\p{IsHan}"

Comment: actually, the edit history shows that you also wrote `InHan`, @Robert only added formatting so the expression appears monospaced

Comment: Hint: You can *choose* to edit it yourself to correct your error. ;-)

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to do it in Java, though. The question is tagged "flex-lexer".

Answer (score -1):

just like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    compile, err := regexp.Compile("\\p{Han}") // match one any Chinese character
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    str := compile.FindString("hello 世界")
    fmt.Println(str) // output: 世
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.