# Regex to allow non-ascii and foreign letters?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is it possible to create a regular expression to allow non-ascii letters along with Latin alphabets, for example Chinese or Greek symbols(eg. A汉语AbN漢語 allowed)?

I currently have the following `^[\w\d][\w\d_\-\.\s]*$` which only allows Latin alphabets.

Comment: Use Chinese characters in a regular expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576384/use-regular-expression-to-match-any-chinese-character-in-utf-8-encoding

Comment: I want to be able to allow all none-latin chars.

Comment: Which language/regex flavor are you using? This is crucial information.

Comment: By the way, `\w` already contains `\d` and `_`, so you don't need the latter.

Comment: "All non-latin chars (in addition to latin chars)" - so basically, *anything*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET,

```
^[\p{L}\d_][\p{L}\d_.\s-]*$
```

is equivalent to your regex, additionally allowing other Unicode letters.

**Explanation:**

`\p{L}` is a shorthand for the Unicode property "Letter".

Caveat: I *think* you wanted to not allow the underscore as initial character (evidenced by its presence only in the second character class). Since `\w` includes the underscore, your regex did allow it, though. You might want to remove it from the first character class in my solution (it's *not* included in `\p{L}`, of course).

In ECMAScript, things are not so easy. You would have to define your own Unicode character ranges. Fortunately, a fellow StackOverflow user has already risen to the occasion and designed a JavaScript regex converter:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933546/20670

Comment: hi, it seems like it isnt working, only allows digits and _. is it dependent on the .net framework version?!

Comment: its being retrieved from a resource file, and inserted into validationexpression="<%$ H:VT.DimensionNameNoneAscii %>"

Comment: Oh, is that something that runs client-side in the browser? Then it can only use ECMAScript regexes, and those don't support Unicode properties.

Comment: so, is there a way to get the same functionality using EMACScript regexes?