# How to allow textbox / editbox to accept English and foreign language characters and numbers but not symbol?

Tags: c#, regex, textbox, editbox

I have an online leaderboard where players come from all over the world to enter their score. In my app, I want to restrict the player's name to English alphanumeric and foreign language characters but no special symbol allowed.

This data is saved into an online mysql database.

I know I can check for English alphanumeric using the following

```
  string correctedName = Regex.Replace(settings.PlayerNameSetting, @"[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+", "");
```

but how about allowing to accept Japanese, Chinese, Spanish or other languages characters too?

Answer (score 0):

In .Net,

```
^[\p{L}\d_][\p{L}\d_.\s-]*$
```

is equivalent to your regex, additionally allowing other Unicode letters.

**Explanation:**

`\p{L}` is a shorthand for the Unicode property "Letter".

Caveat: I think you wanted to not allow the underscore as initial character (evidenced by its presence only in the second character class). Since `\w` includes the underscore, your regex did allow it, though. You might want to remove it from the first character class in my solution (it's not included in `\p{L}`, of course).

In ECMAScript, things are not so easy. You would have to define your own Unicode character ranges. Fortunately, a fellow StackOverflow user has already risen to the occasion and designed a JavaScript regex converter:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933546/20670

Comment: Thanks but this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/13069420/1740600