# Regex for Chinese numerals in java

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

The regular expression `\p{N}` is not recognising Chinese numerals.

Please suggest correct regex in Java for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use regular expression to match ANY Chinese character in utf-8 encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576384/use-regular-expression-to-match-any-chinese-character-in-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on this article on Wikipedia [Chinese numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_numerals#Standard_numbers):

- Common numerals: 0 to 10, hundred, thousand, ten thousand, hundred million

  零〇一二三四五六七八九十百千: `\u96f6\u3007\u4e00\u4e8c\u4e09\u56db\u4e94\u516d\u4e03\u516b\u4e5d\u5341\u767e\u5343`

  (Simplified) 万亿: `\u4e07\u4ebf`
  (Traditional) 萬億: `\u842c\u5104`
- Financial use

  (Simplified) 零壹贰叁肆伍陆柒捌玖拾佰仟萬億: `\u96f6\u58f9\u8d30\u53c1\u8086\u4f0d\u9646\u67d2\u634c\u7396\u62fe\u4f70\u4edf\u842c\u5104`
  (Traditional) 零壹貳參肆伍陸柒捌玖拾佰仟萬億: `\u96f6\u58f9\u8cb3\u53c3\u8086\u4f0d\u9678\u67d2\u634c\u7396\u62fe\u4f70\u4edf\u842c\u5104`

  The 2 versions differs at 2, 3, and 6. Some of them overlap with common numerals.
- Large number beyond 10<sup>12</sup> and up to 10<sup>44</sup>

  (Traditional) 兆京垓秭穰溝澗正載: `\u5146\u4eac\u5793\u79ed\u7a70\u6e9d\u6f97\u6b63\u8f09`
  (Simplified) 兆京垓秭穰沟涧正载: `\u5146\u4eac\u5793\u79ed\u7a70\u6c9f\u6da7\u6b63\u8f7d`

  The 2 versions differs at the 6th, 7th and 9th characters.

  (Some other alternatives) 經经杼壤: `\u7d93\u7ecf\u677c\u58e4`
- Regional usage

  (Traditional) 兩: `\u5169`
  (Simplified) 两: `\u4e24`

  Of note is the character above. Others are not commonly used.