# Check if string contains CJK (chinese) characters

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I need to check if a string contains chinese characters.
After searching i found that i have to look with the regex on this pattern `\u31C0-\u31EF`,
But i don't manage to get the regex work.

Anyone experienced with this situation ? is the regex correct ?

Comment: Using `"[\u31C0-\u31EF]"` will indeed match any character whose code point is in the range `0x31C0` to `0x31EF`.  You need the square brackets.  I have no idea whether the actual numbers are correct; there are only 48 characters in this range, and I thought CJK had a lot more than that, but what do I know?

Comment: There's definitely more characters in CJK, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs).

Comment: The duplicate is not marked with a java tag. Is this really a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576410/2589776), in Java 7 (i.e. regex compiler meets [requirement RL1.2 Properties from UTS#18 *Unicode Regular Expressions*](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Categories)), you can use the following regex to match a Chinese (well, CJK) character:

```
\p{script=Han}
```

which can be appreviated to simply

```
\p{Han}
```