# String.contains function not working

Tags: java, string, list, contains

I have to check whether the words from File1 exist in File2 or not and then count. Data in both files is shown below.

The words in File1 are like shown below:

1. 发表
2. 发愁
3. 发达
4. 发抖
5. 发挥

The data in File2 is like shown below:

1. 这篇论文是什么时候发表的？
2. 91 ．数据 删掉 被马工程师 了
3. 92 ．驾驶 酒后 很大 危害
4. 93 ．客观地 要 他人 评价
5. 94 ．我不小心 水壶 打翻 了 把

The code I have written is as follows:

```
File file1 = new File("ChineseWord.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file1));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(sc.hasNext()){
                list.add(sc.next());
        }

        sc.close();

        File file2 = new File("RandomData.txt");

        Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file2));

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            while(newScanner.hasNext()){

                String word = newScanner.nextLine();
                String toMatch = list.get(i);

                if(word.contains(toMatch)){
                    System.out.println("Success");
                    count++;
                }


            }

            String test = list.get(i);
            newList.add(test+"exists" + count+ "times");
            count =0;

        }
```

The question is that it returns 0 for all words whereas the very first word in File1 exists in the very first line of File2. If I manually do something like this

```
if(word.contains("发表")){
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        count++;
                    }
```

It prints successs otherwise it does not ? Why is this so?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048692/check-if-string-contains-cjk-chinese-characters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357938/detect-chinese-character-in-java

Comment: I would make sure the character encoding read is the one you wrote.  You could try UTF-8 or UTF-16LE, but you have to be consistent.

Comment: The character encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is within your logic, because you loop over each words in `list`, but your scanner on "File2" is only created **once** outside this `list`-loop.

You probably should move the list-loop just over the `if (word.contains(toMatch))`.

---

Following your comment, I did a quick test with:

```
package so36862093;

import com.google.common.io.Resources;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final File file1 = new File(Resources.getResource("so36862093/ChineseWord.txt").toURI());
        final List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(file1.toPath());
        final File file2 = new File(Resources.getResource("so36862093/RandomData.txt").toURI());
        final Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file2));
        final Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();

        while(newScanner.hasNext()){
            final String word = newScanner.nextLine();

            for (String toMatch : list) {
                if(word.contains(toMatch)){
                    System.out.println("Success");
                    count.put(toMatch, count.getOrDefault(toMatch, 0) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : count.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + " exists " + e.getValue() + " times.");
        }
    }
}
```

and in `ChineseText.txt` (UTF-8)

```
发表
发愁
发达
发抖
发挥
```

and in `RandomData.txt` (UTF-8):

[image: For some reason this text cannot be copy pasted]

The output is

```
Success
发表 exists 1 times.
```

---

Follow-up: I played a little with the project you shared, and the issue is that you have a non breaking space [U+65279](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) at the start of every line (I did not).

**Illustration:**
[image: debug session]

So, you should probably ["strip"](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAll(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) that character before anything else.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The for loop was inside the while loop and I have been doing a lot of things so that's why i posted my last code and it was a little messed up. The problem is that it does not give success for the very first word if you try that? Why is that so?

Comment: The fixed code works for me, you should double check your code and inputs.

Comment: I just copied your code as it is. Checked all the text files encoding but it does not work for me? What is wrong in it?

Comment: can you zip your inputs and share them?

Comment: By inputs you mean what? Should I zip my whole project and share the link?

Comment: Thank you very much. I also just debugged and checked it. It was showing an empty space at char[0].

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are reading the entire file and then comparing that with the 1st element in your list, where it should be the other way around, Read 1st line from file2 and compare that with entire list.

Change your code to ->

```
while(newScanner.hasNext()){
    String word = newScanner.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String toMatch = list.get(i);

        if(word.contains(toMatch)){
            System.out.println("Success");
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I totally understand that. I have deleted all the words from file 1 except the very first 1.  if(word.contains("发表")){
              System.out.println("Success");
                 count++;
             } is working and not the other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the encoding:

```
 Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file2),"UNICODE");
```

Try that:

```
    File file1 = new File("data/ChineseWord.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file1),"UNICODE");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(sc.hasNext()){
            list.add(sc.next());
    }

    sc.close();

    File file2 = new File("data/RandomData.txt");
    Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file2),"UNICODE");

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        while(newScanner.hasNext()){

            String word = newScanner.nextLine();
            String toMatch = list.get(i);

            if(word.contains(toMatch)){
                System.out.println("Success");
                count++;
            }


        }

        String test = list.get(i);
        newList.add(test+"exists" + count+ "times");
        count =0;

    }
```

Comment: No it does not work. The output in console has been changed to some weird characters.