# preg_replace keep the space if start with a-z and end with a-z

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace any space in `$string` with an underline

but NOT if the space is surrounded by [a-z]

```
$string = '@@ @@ English something else';
```

I tried this but it replaces "@@ @@" to "@_@"

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-z]\s[^a-z]/ui', '_' , $string);
```

I want the output to look like this

```
@@_@@_English something else
```

---

sorry i don't know how to use code in comment, so just add a reply

tested the 2nd and 3rd pattern also work

i understand the 2nd one, but the 3rd one a bit hard for me LOL

i need to go check https://www.regular-expressions.info/

```
$string = '英文名 中文名 Peter Wong，John Tam，Sam Hu';
$string = preg_replace('/(?<![a-z]) | (?![a-z])/i', '，', $string);
```

output is

```
英文名，中文名，Peter Wong，John Tam，Sam Hu
```

because CJK Name is no space between each char, so this solved the big problem for me

worked like a charm ;)

Thankyou @mickmackusa

Comment: What language is this? 英文 中文

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to include the `u` unicode flag for this task.

Simply disqualify the undesirable spaces with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` then replace all qualifying spaces.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8ad67adafedf48c8926e81d19555073bc3b3112)) ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kg9Ycj/1))

```
$string = '英文 中文 English something else';
echo preg_replace('/[a-z] [a-z](*SKIP)(*FAIL)| /i','_',$string);
```

Output:

```
英文_中文_English something else
```

Pattern Explanation:

`[a-z] [a-z](*SKIP)(*FAIL)` <-- this means match and discard the letter-space-letter occurrences
`|` <-- this mean "OR"
 <-- this will match every non-discarded space in the string (only these will be replaced

---

Two alternatives with lookarounds will also work (and faster): ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kg9Ycj/2))

```
/(?<![a-z]) | (?![a-z])/i
```

---

Fastest of all will be the `\B` (negated version of the word boundary metacharacter): ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kg9Ycj/4))

```
/\B | \B/
```

Comment: must follow a | and the space ? never know this (*SKIP)(*FAIL) very useful

Comment: I've added a little more explanation about the pattern.  (and, yes, I agree `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is VERY useful.)

Comment: @kenken9999 I just added a couple of new (faster) patterns that will provide the same effect on your sample input.  Just thought I'd let you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language that is but I found this: [Use regular expression to match ANY Chinese character in utf-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576384/use-regular-expression-to-match-any-chinese-character-in-utf-8-encoding)

Your regular expression needs to contain (all) Chinese characters, which can be expressed as:

`\p{Han}`

Here is PHP's documentation on Unicode characters and a list of supported scripts: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: oh sorry, this is chinese, i edited the question, actually is the same case

Comment: This post offers three fractional pieces of advice; two of which are just links.  This post would be better positioned as a comment under the question as it doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Just a suggestion... ;]