# How to write a multilingual regular expression for Name in Japanese and English?

Tags: javascript

I have written a regular expression for Name validation `^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$`  in English language and now I need it to support Japanese language too. So how to write regular expression validation in JavaScript.

Comment: Validate the name of what?

Comment: First Name and Last Name of a person

Comment: What is the point of this? What are you trying to exclude? Whatever regexp you come up with will yield false positives (says it's a name, but actually it isn't), and false negatives (says it's not a name, but actually it is), leaving somebody very frustrated.

Comment: I am trying to exclude special characters and digits in name. And validate name is in English or Japanese Language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use regular expression to match ANY Chinese character in utf-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576384/use-regular-expression-to-match-any-chinese-character-in-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we expect unicode. To match against  range use this form of regex `[\u{hhhh}-\u{hhhh}]` . Find the appropriate range you want to support you can use [this page](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml)    for reference. Finally don't forget to enable unicode flag `/$[\u{hhhh}-\u{hhhh}]+^/u`. Here is an example which will match against a word consisting of only katakana characters

```
/^[\u{30a0}-\u{30ff}]+$/u
```

Or use this range to include japanese punctuation.

```
/^\u[{3000}-\u{303f}\u{30a0}-\u{30ff}]+$/u
```

Complete example

```js
console.log("Merlin Thomas".match(/^[a-zA-Z \u{30a0}-\u{30ff}\s]+$/u))
console.log("メルリントーマス".match(/^[a-zA-Z \u{30a0}-\u{30ff}\s]+$/u))
```

Comment: I am using  this regualr expression `^[a-zA-Z \\u4E00-\\u9FD5\\s]+$` but its not working

Comment: Don't forget u flag.

Comment: I suggest you add the input you hope to match against  and the regex you are using and edit your original question. It would be easier to help this way.

Comment: Example -
It should except in English Name - Merlin Thomas
and Japanese Name- メルリントーマス

Comment: run  `"メルリントーマス".match(/^[a-zA-Z \u{30a0}-\u{30ff}\s]+$/u)`