# Filtering criteria for rows that only contain certain Chinese characters

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr, cjk

Suppose `table_a` consists of a column of approximately 1,500 unique Chinese characters and `table_b` consists of a column of approximately 50,000 unique Chinese character combinations (multi-character phrases, sentences, etc. of differing lengths).

I would like to be able to filter through `table_b` and return only the rows in which the character combinations **only** contain characters from the character column in `table_a`. Ideally, this code should also ignore any alphanumeric characters and punctuation.

Is there a way to easily do this in R, preferably in base R or with functions within the tidyverse (dplyr, stringr, etc.)? I thought about using the `stringr` package and regular expressions, but I'm not familiar with how that works with Chinese characters.

To slightly simplify the problem, consider the following example:

```
vec_a <- c("你","好","吗","不")
vec_b <- c("你好","你好吗？","我很好","我不好")
```

From these two lists, I'd like to return `vec_c`, which is `c("你好","你好吗？")`.

I'm thinking that whatever logic/function is used for this will be able to be used within dyplyr's filter function to achieve my goal.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576384/use-regular-expression-to-match-any-chinese-character-in-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: According to that post, you can use regexp with Chinese characters. So you should be able to do it with `stringr`

Comment: In base regex, `grep(paste0("^[", paste(vec_a, collapse = ""), "]+$"), vec_b, value = TRUE)`. With stringr, `str_subset(vec_b, paste0("^[", paste(vec_a, collapse = ""), "]+$"))`

Comment: Both methods by @alistaire work fine. To get what you want, you may need to add "?" to `list_a`, or find an alternative way to deal with `?`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on alistaire's  and Zhiqiang Wang, comments, what you want is the following:

```
pattern = paste0("^[", paste(vec_a, collapse = ""), "[:punct:]]+$")
```

Then `grep(pattern, vec_b, value = TRUE)` or `str_subset(vec_b, pattern)` will work.

`[:punct:]` adds a match for any punctuation character (see [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) for more information).